# Trying to refer to self inside a has_many scope in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, has-many-through

I have the following setup:

```
class TeamEnrollment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :team
    has_many :term_enrollments, through: :team
end
```

The above code works fine.  Now I need to change the has_many line to look like this:

```
has_many :term_enrollments, 
   -> {where("(term_enrollments.term_start_date <= ? AND term_enrollments.term_end_date >= ?) OR (term_enrollments.term_start_date >= ? AND term_enrollments.term_end_date > ?) OR (term_enrollments.term_start_date <= ? AND term_enrollments.term_end_date >= ?)", self.start_date, self.start_date, self.start_date, self.termination_date, self.termination_date, self.termination_date)}
   , through: :team
```

From the code above, I get the following error if I try to do `TeamEnrollment.first.term_enrollments`:

```
undefined method `start_date' for #<TermEnrollment::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007ff706550550>
```

I have tested the `where` clause with the first configuration of code above and it works fine.  It's only when in the `has_many` clause that it does not work.
I'm pretty sure it has to do with the use of self inside of the `has_many through`.  I'm trying to refer to the TeamEnrollment's start_date.  How Do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`has_many`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many-label-Scopes) documentation section about scopes shows the following example:

> ```
> has_many :posts, ->(blog) { where("max_post_length > ?", blog.max_post_length) }
> ```

That example shows that the `scope` can take a parameter, which is the record it's being called on